# passing the function parameter value to the function inside that function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this script which works fine but i want it to move to common js file.

```
function commonSelect2(selector,url,id,text){
    selector.select2({
        minimumInputLength:1,
        placeholder:"Select Parent Menu",
        ajax: {
            type:"post",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    term: term, //search term
                    page_limit: 10 // page size
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page ) {
                var newData = [];
                $.each(data, function (index,value) {
                    newData.push({
                        id: value.id,  //id part present in data
                        text: value.text  //string to be displayed
                    });
                });
                return { results: newData };
            }
        }
    });
}
```

mostly it is done except the part of `id` and `text` parameter.

Here is how i send parameters

```
var selector = $('#selectParentMenu');
var url = "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/loadAllParentFormNames/";
var id = "FormID";
var text = "FormName";
commonSelect2(selector,url,id,text);
```

problem is that

```
id: value.id,  //id part present in data
text: value.text  //string to be displayed
```

the `value.id` and `value.text` do not recognize the `id` and `text` is of parameters.

it works if i do like this

```
id: value.FormID,  //id part present in data
text: value.FormName  //string to be displayed
```

but if i put parameters containing these values don't work.

Comment: Try `value[id]` and `value[text]`

Comment: @grin0048
OMG, and i thought it might not be possible..i wonder how good are you guys.. Many Thanks, it works..
Plz if possible explain why it works like in array form but not the way as it was intended to. `value.FormID` was working fine but when gave value of `FormID` to variable `text` i now have to use as like array.
May i know what changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` and `text` parameters are strings containing the names of the properties you are trying to access in your `value` object. To access properties dynamically like that requires the `value[id]` syntax.

Comment: At first I didn't understand, this other SO question explains it further and now I get it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: Problem is solved but i still don't get it. why then `value.FormID` and `value.FormName` worked.
Seems like javascript/jQuery is not easy to learn.

Comment: Think of it like this. `value.FormID` is the same as `value['FormId']`. `value.id` is the same as `value['id']`... that's why it doesn't work, it's looking for a property called `id`.